# Firebase Notification Not Showing on Android Device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop a module that will show notifications using Firebase. This module has a 3 function to subscribe and unsubscribe from topics. It also has the two services mentioned in the firebase [sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience)

I know that it is working because it is syncing topics with Firebase console. New topics are being created.

This module is connected to the main app module which uses it.

My problem is that when a notification is sent, I don't receive.

Firebase module code :

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ineqe.firebasenotification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- for plugin -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">


        <service
            android:name=".AbleFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**AbleFirebaseMessagingService**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.ineqe.able.library.MainActivity;

public class AbleFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "AbleFirebaseService";
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived (RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
            // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
            // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
            // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
            // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
            // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
            // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
            // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            // Check if message contains a data payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            }

            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }

            // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
            // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        }
        // [END receive_message]

        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
         *
         * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
         */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    }
```

**FirebaseIDService**

```
package com.ineqe.firebasenotification;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

/**
 * Created by brendan on 26/10/2016.
 */

public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

**FireBasePushService**

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.ineqe.able.library.PushService;

/**
 * Created by brendan on 25/10/2016.
 */

public class FireBasePushService implements PushService {
    @Override
    public void initialize() {

        Log.v("Token", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("global");
    }

    @Override
    public void addChannel(String channel) {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChannel(String channel) {

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(channel);
    }
}
```

Also I will add the manifest, gradle.build file and the main activity file to show how I reference the firebase module.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ineqe.hsct.fostering">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <permission
     android:name="com.ineqe.hsct.fostering.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.ineqe.hsct.fostering.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



         <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
             android:resource="@drawable/ic_not" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WalkthroughActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StafDirectoryDetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExpansionActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
import com.ineqe.firebasenotification.FireBasePushService;

public class MyApplication extends com.ineqe.able.library.MyApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        setMainActivity(MainActivity.class);
        setTintAppColor("#00b5cc");
        setSplashImage("hsctf_splash_bg");
        setAppTracker("UA-42956664-12");
        FireBasePushService ps = new FireBasePushService();
        ps.initialize();
        setPushService(ps);
        setLoginImage("hsctf_login_bg");
        setSchool(true);
        setTesting(false);
        setAnswersPage(true);
        setExpansionFiles(false);
        super.onCreate();

    }


}
```

**Gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ineqe.hsct.fostering"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile project(':able')
    compile project(":firebasenotification")


}
```

What I know right now is :

1. The app can talk to firebase console and create new topics.
2. Notification doesn't seem to arrive even when I use the token for the specific device I am working with.

If you have any ideas don't hesitate to comment

Comment: By not receiving any messages, do you just mean that there is no notification shown in the device or totally nothing is received (`onMessageReceived()` not called)?

Comment: OnMessageRecieve is not called. No Notifications are shown. Also Log messages doesn't show.

Comment: Are you sending a notification from the Firebase Console or from your own App Server? Is there any error?

Comment: From Firebase console directly. No errors show in the logs from what I can see. The device was able to talk to firebase and make new topics.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. Why are there 2 manifest files?

Comment: One for the main app. One for the module that handles Firebase messaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out where my mistake is. the line :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

should be added to build.gradle for app module, not the firebase module. In addition, when creating the project the correct way is to enter the package for the app module and save the google-services.json file in the app module not the other firebase module.

To reuse the firebase module (if you have one), always remember to do it as mentioned previously.

Comment: Are you getting the notification when app is removed from the Recent used Apps?

Answer (score 0):

First add this filter in firebaseMessanging service:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
```

In firebaseMessanging:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
       ShowNotification(notification, data);
    }

    private void ShowNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");


        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(data.get("title"))
                .setContentText(data.get("text"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("ANY")
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1000, 300);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

And In FIrebaseIDservice:

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("GLOBALgroup");

       // sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);   Your METHOD to save TOKENS
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did as you suggested but still nothing shows. It is true I wasn't calling the function to show notification however the logs wasn't showing anything. any ideas ?

Comment: I mean how you sending notification? from Firebase console or PHP?

Comment: Firebase console using the package name for the firebase library.

Comment: My code is working using PHP api, but u can send notification using DATA. In  console use advance tab to send notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126709/discussion-between-divyesh-and-amr-yousef).